# jQuery Masonry. Update columnWidth on resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, fluid-layout

I'm trying to figure out how to change the columnWidth of my fluid masonry layout when the browser window is resized. So when the browser width is less that 1300px the columnWidth switches from 4 to 3.
Here's my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('#thumb-wrap, #thumb-wrap-2').masonry({
          itemSelector: '#thumb-container-1, #thumb-container-2',
          // set columnWidth a fraction of the container width
          columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
            return containerWidth / 4;
          }

          });
    });
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about redefining by window resize?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#thumb-wrap, #thumb-wrap-2').masonry({
        itemSelector: '#thumb-container-1, #thumb-container-2',
        columnWidth: function(containerWidth) {
            var num = (containerWidth > 1300) ? 4 : 3;
            return containerWidth / num;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: very close, this successfully switches down from 4 to 3, but the masonry isn't working when the page loads, only when you start to resize the window does it snap into place?

Comment: You can use the contents of this function on page.load event as well. By the way, I just looked at masonry options and there's isResizable (Triggers layout logic when browser window is resized). Have you tried it?

Comment: I sort of got it working, it still doesn't work when the page is loaded at a smaller size, and I was having issues with it when the screen size is increased again and it goes back to 4 columns, the media queries don't seem to be applied

Comment: @user1374796 Did you ever get this working? I'm stuck with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496769/changing-a-parameter-based-on-browser-window-width?noredirect=1#comment34226588_22496769