# Changing a parameter based on browser window width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

With [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), I'm using the following code to change `columnWidth` to `320` when the width of the screen or the browser window is reduced to less than `1035px`. When the width of the screen is greater than `1035px`, `columnWidth` is supposed to be `240`.

However, the code below causes `columnWidth` to stay at `320` regardless of the width of the screen. For example, you can see what I'm talking about with the blogs on this site: http://keebs.com/sandbox

On full screen, it looks like this:

[image]

When the browser is resized down to less than 1035px in width, it looks like this:

[image]

Basically, for the first image, I want the number of columns to be 3 so the blogs could fill up the empty space. In order to get the number of columns to 3, I'd have to change `columnWidth` to `240`.

So here's the code!

```
if(jQuery().isotope) {

    $container = jQuery('#masonry');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: $(document).width() > 1035 ? 240 : 320
            },
            getSortData: {

                order: function($elem) {
                    return parseInt($elem.attr('data-order'));
                }

            },
            sortBy: 'order'
        }, function() {

            // Isotope Chrome Fix   
            setTimeout(function () {        
                jQuery('#masonry').isotope('reLayout'); 
            }, 1000);

        });


    }); 

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $container = jQuery('#masonry');

    jQuery('#filter li').click(function(){

        jQuery('#filter li').removeClass('active's);
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');

        var selector = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('data-filter');

        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

        return false;

    });


}
```

Comment: Donot set width on masonry events , Please set width on css media query

Comment: @Shibin Doesn't Masonry require a change in the JavaScript? When I change the width through CSS, the number of columns don't change.

Comment: Is problem when you browser resizing or something another time ?

Comment: @Shibin When I resize my browser, it's ok because the number of columns is 2 (320px wide). When the width of the browser is wider than 1035px, I want the columns to change to 3 (240px wide).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use responsive desing in your css.

```
@media screen and(max-width:700px)
{
  //your css content goes here depending what you wanna show when screen resizes to 700px,this will work good in mobiles also
}
```

Comment: I am using media queries but Masonry requires the JavaScript to be changed. Unless I've overlooked something...